# How to avoid Spider(web crawler) to crawl already crawled website?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, scrapy

I am running a spider with certain input URLs and am saving the URLs in S3 bucket. The structure in which I am saving it in S3 bucket is that first there is a folder with its name as the date (eg- 6/11/2019) and inside that are the subfolders with the website names as the name of subfolders containing the URLs of pages of that particular website. Many times, the spider crawls through the same website and saves it in S3 bucket.

So, I want to prevent the spider from crawling the websites which were crawled a few days before and also I want to remove all the duplicate subfolders from S3 bucket.

Comment: Save the names of the pages somewhere

Comment: What did you try to solve it? Read all foldernames into a set, substract that set of names from the names you want to crawl, done. Where is your specific problem and your code as [mre] that replicates the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the list of already crawled pages somewhere, and not visit these pages. You can get it from S3 directly, or alternatively some kind of persistent storage, such as Redis or dynamo, or even a relational DB.